# maria db json support

Tags: json, eloquent, mariadb

My situation is: the php server uses MariaDB (the version which doesn't support json data type). Is it ok if I changed the data type from json to text? I am also using Eloquent so it casts data to json when retrieves it from db. I worry whether there will be some data loss or deformatrion if I store JSON arrays in TEXT?
Thank you!

Comment: It _probably_ needs to be `CHARACTER SET utf8mb4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, JSON values in MariaDB 10.2 are supposed to be stored in `TEXT` fields of a suitable size, so generally it should work all right. Whether it's properly compatible with the universe of 3rd-party applications, remains to be seen. Naturally, before making big changes, create a backup.